# How install the latest PHP minor branch version with composer

Tags: php, composer-php

I am trying to manage branch with version number to have a control of the code. So I have a branch "0.7" and from this I create another branch "0.7.1" with a lot of changes.

I'm trying to install in other project my package with "0.7.1" branch code, and as the composer documentation say, the way to do this is define the jida dependency as "0.7.x-dev". But when I run "composer update" composer only download the 0.7 version and not the latest. I tried a lot of things but i can't download the 0.7.1 version. I want to fix this because my idea is later make a 0.7.2 versions and keep like that.

```
{
  "type": "website",
  "minimum-stability": "dev",
  "license": "mit",
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "jr0driguez",
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    "phpmailer/phpmailer": "^5.2",
    "ext-json": "*",
    "ext-gd": "*",
    "jida/framework": "0.7.x-dev",
    "ext-curl": "*"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\": [
        "./Aplicacion/"
      ]
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
      "npm install"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
      "npm update"
    ]
  }
}
```

I put an image with composer message where shows the "[image: Available versions]"

Comment: In the consuming composer.json you need `"minimum-stability": "dev"`

Comment: I have this. Let me update the post content to set all  package.json code.

Comment: See: https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/aliases.md#branch-alias  which needs to be setup in `jidadesarrollos/jida` composer and something like `"0.7": "0.7.x-dev"` for  alias.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone you know if I need wait some time? I remove the 0.7 branch for jida repository. I add the alias in  jida/framework composer file, I run "composer clearcache" and when I run "composer update" this still instaling the "0.7" version instead of 0.7.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the trouble adding  the "repositories" property into the composer.json from the project where I was installing the dependency.

This was the part:

```
 {
      "type": "git",
      "url": "https://github.com/jidadesarrollos/jida",
      "name": "jida/framework"
 }
```

I set the "name" property to cofirm the dependency name, I think must be the same. And with this I could specify the branch name that I was needing to install

```
"jida/framework": "dev-desarrollo",
```

The branch where I'am working. I hope the post be useful to another.

Answer (score 0):

If your branch name is `0.7.1`, you should use `0.7.1.x-dev` as a constraint:

```
"jida/framework": "0.7.1.x-dev",
```

Comment: this trouble is taking me a lot of time. I tried this but that version is not available. I'll update the post to show the composer message with the availaible versions.

Comment: I'm able to install this branch if I add your git repo as vcs repository in `composer.json`: `- Installing jida/framework (0.7.1.x-dev 1e2ad00): Cloning 1e2ad00ae5 from cache`. Are you sure that your git repo is configured to trigger refresh  info on packagist? Did you tried to refresh it manually?

Comment: I could fix this adding the "repositories" entry into package.json project that i am installing the dependency. and in this entry I set "type": "git" and  the github url. Is it the same that you say?

Comment: No, I think you don't need to use `git`/`vcs` repository, you should fix your package configuration on packagist. It looks like last changes in GitHub repo are not fetched by packagist - last commit on master was 10 days ago, but packagist displays version from `2018-12-23 10:19 UTC`.